# how can i solve crystal report issue?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

this code is working but i am facing some error link the report call normally but 
the ask every time parameter and db connection.

```
    private void showReport(int? clsID,int? secID,int? facID)
        {
            try
            {
                crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
                ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
                rd.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\Reports\\ttreport1.rpt");
                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
                var data = obj.st_getTimeTableReprot(clsID, secID, facID);
                rd.SetDataSource(data.ToList());

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MainClass.ShowMSF(ex.Message, "Error", "Error");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best answer, as it involves hardcoding credentials, but hey, I was desperate.  Below is an example of what I used the other day when my Crystal Report I'm calling in my ASP.NET/C# project wouldn't stop prompting me for credentials every time I ran it.

I'd try hardcoding the credentials you use to generate your report data and see if that helps.

protected void BtnTagNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string btn_fileSavePath;

```
    btn_fileSavePath = @"\\myserver\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\myReport.RPT";
    ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();

    TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
    TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
    ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
    Tables CrTables;

    string path = btn_fileSavePath;
    cryRpt.Load(path);

    cryRpt.SetParameterValue("TagNo", Convert.ToInt32(txtTagNo.Text));

    crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "YOURSERVER\\HERE";
    crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "DBNAME";
    crConnectionInfo.UserID = "userID";
    crConnectionInfo.Password = "password";

    CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables;
    foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
    {
        crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
        crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
        CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
    }

    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;

}
```